# Trying to read a two's complement 16bit into a signed decimal

Tags: php, python, math, binary

Im trying (in PHP) to read the two's complement value of two bytes (16 bits) and return a signed decimal.

I am not sure how the two's compliment math *should* work, but from php.net, I managed to get it almost to show what I expect. The issue i think I am having is that I do not get any negative values.

Code I have:

```
function _bin16dec($bin) {
    // Function to convert 16bit binary numbers to integers using two's complement
    $num = bindec($bin);
    if($num > 0xFFFF) { return false; }
    if($num >= 0x8000) {
        return -(($num ^ 0xFFFF)+1);
    } else {
        return $num;
    }
}
```

This code is what someone came up with online, but its in python which do not understand.

```
def twoscomp( x ) :
   "This returns a 16-bit signed number (two's complement)"
   if (0x8000 & x): 
   x = - (0x010000 - x)
return x
```

The application reads two bytes from a gyroscope for each axis in the 2's compliment form.

Thanks in advance!

Sam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this Python function does what you expect...

```py
def twoscomp( x ) :
    """This returns a 16-bit signed number (two's complement)"""
    if (0x8000 & x): 
        x = - (0x010000 - x)
    return x
```

...this PHP function should do the exact same thing.

```php
function _bin16dec($bin) {
    // converts 16bit binary number string to integer using two's complement
    $num = bindec($bin) & 0xFFFF; // only use bottom 16 bits
    if (0x8000 & $num) {
        $num = - (0x010000 - $num);
    }
    return $num;
}
```

This code works for me on PHP 5.3.15. Let me know if you would like further explanation.
--ap

Comment: That works! Im getting reading from my gyro! Thanks. All I have to do now is convert from the decimal your code returns into degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version for a ec-2 Amazon Linux x64 distro, PHP 5.3.27, that converts 32bit binary strings:

```
function _bin32dec($bin) {
  $num = bindec($bin) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
  if (0x80000000 & $num) {
    $num = - (0xFFFFFFFF - $num + 1);
  }
  return $num;
}
```